# How to draw a right angle triangle using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to draw a right angle triangle with tkinter. I can't figure out how to do it, I can do a rectangle and then another one but I cant get the second rectangle to be a triangle.

Here's an example of what I want to do, how far I have gotten, and my code:

What I want to do:
[image]

How far I've gotten: [image]

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
can = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
can.pack()
shape1={'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'kind': 'rect', 'fill': True}
shape2={'bounds': [80, 50, 20, 35], 'kind': 'tri', 'fill': True}
can.create_rectangle(list(shape1.values())[0],fill='black')
can.create_rectangle(list(shape2.values())[0],fill='white')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `polygon`-function to draw a triangle. Just specify a `list` of corner-points of your triangle as argument.

```py
points = [x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3]
can.create_polygon(points, fill='white')
```

Check out the [tkinter-documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_polygon.html) for more info.

Comment: Great! :) Feel free to accept an answer that helped you, it will help others looking for the same information as you were.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `create_polygon()` to draw triangle:

```py
shape2={'bounds': [20, 50, 80, 35, 80, 50], 'kind': 'tri', 'fill': True}
can.create_polygon(list(shape2.values())[0],fill='white',outline='white')
```